# What's the proper way to do async calls in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, promise, ember-cli

For a specific service call, I'm using jQuery instead of ember data:

```
return Ember.$.get(url).then((json) => {
  this.store.pushPayload('user', json);
  return this.store.getById('user', json.user.id);
});
```

This breaks ember's testing:

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun.
>                     You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in a run

I can fix this by adding a run inside my promise's .then function:

```
return Ember.$.get(url).then((json) => {
  Ember.run(() => {
    this.store.pushPayload('user', json);
    return this.store.getById('user', json.user.id);
  })
});
```

This doesn't work for me though, because Ember.run(..) doesn't return anything, so my promise resolves to undefined.  I've seen some suggestions to move Ember.run out one level so it wraps the method returning the promise instead.  This will then return the correct value, but the tests will continue to fail.

What's the proper way to return a promise that resolves to a value, while not breaking tests?

Thanks!

**Edit 1**

I did get it working with this code:

```
var self = this;
return Ember.$.get(url).then((json) => {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      Ember.run(function() {
        self.store.pushPayload('user', json);
        var user = self.store.getById('user', json.user.id);
        debugger;
        resolve(user);
      });
    });
});
```

Is this the right way to do it?  It feels like a lot of added complexity just to do an ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And now there's an even newer/fancier thing to use: [Ember Fetch](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-fetch).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your async call in an [`Ember.RSVP.Promise`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.Promise.html) then `resolve`. Example (taken from a `route`'s `model` hook):

```
var self = this;
return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Ember.$.get(url).then((json) => {
        var record = self.store.pushPayload('user', json);
        Ember.run(null, resolve, record);
        return record;
    });
});
```

Comment: Please no, use an `Ember.RSVP.resolve` on the $.get` instead of creating an explicit new promise.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  store.pushPayload doesn't return a value, so that shortcut doesn't work.  Also it still trips up testing.  I did get it working (see edit), but I'm not sure if it's right based on @Benjamin Gruenbaum's comment.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Looks like in Ember 1.13+, the prefered way of doing Ajax is using Ember Ajax - https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax

---

<s>Since you are just using jQuery's `$.ajax` methods, you should be using the "ic-ajax" lib that is actually included in all new Ember projects created with ember-cli.</s>

This library basically does all the wrapping of the JQuery Ajax calls in an `Ember.run` so you can easily test.

For example, using your example:

```
import Ember from 'ember'
....
....
return Ember.$.get(url).then((json) => {
  this.store.pushPayload('user', json);
 return this.store.getById('user', json.user.id);
});
```

would become

```
import Ember from 'ember'
import request from 'ic-ajax'
....
....
return request(url).then((json) => {
    ....
});
```

Much cleaner than having to wrap all your ajax calls in `Ember.run` yourself

Comment: It looks like ember-ajax recommends against using ic-ajax now.

Comment: yup,  added an edit at the top of the post with a link to the ember-ajax repo